# why libpython3.6 is not installing?

Tags: package-management, held-packages

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.6 : Depends: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.6-1~18.04) but 3.6.6-1+xenial1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
libpython3.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.6-1~18.04
  Version table:
     3.6.6-1~18.04 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.6.5-3 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

libpython3.6-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.6.6-1+xenial1
  Candidate: 3.6.6-1+xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.6-1+xenial1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.6-1~18.04 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.6.5-3 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: sounds like you're using PPAs that're breaking things.  Where're you getting the Python 3.6 packages from?

Comment: i am getting this after updating to 18.04.1 lts ubunu @ThomasWard

Comment: Show me your `apt-cache policy libpython3.6` output as an edit to your quesiton.

Comment: @ThomasWard thats the output

Comment: can you also include `apt-cache policy libpython3.6-stdlib` as well, but this time don't erase the other content in your question and just add it as an additional bit of information at the bottom?

Comment: @ThomasWard that's it

Comment: @ThomasWard libpython3.6-stdlib is installed... but what's wrong now?

Comment: You used this ppa while on 16.04 & did not use ppa-purge before upgrading to 18.04 (too bad..) https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial You could easily thru synaptic find out any packages installed from that ppa, get the current 18.04 packages & install all at once with dpkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflict between this two libpython3.6-stdlib versions: 3.6.6-1~18.04, 3.6.6-1+xenial1. Try to install libpython3.6-stdlib. It's possible that apt will offer you to remove this version: 3.6.6-1+xenial1

Comment: but installing it shows me it's already install in newer version.  then how to remove 3.6.6xenial1

Comment: Try to remove 3.6.6-1+xenial1 and install new version: sudo apt-get remove libpython3.6-stdlib && sudo apt-get install libpython3.6